# Uncaught Exception: Permission denied to Proxy.InstallTrigger

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've searched high and low for this and can easily reproduce it. Running absolute latest PHP SDK and the JS is coming directly from facebook over an HTTPS connection. My 'MyAppId' and domain have been changed in the code that follows. Substitute your own to reproduce.

This is with Firefox 8 and Firebug.

Code to reproduce:
`

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
         FB.init({
        appId: 'MyAppID', 
        status: true, 
        oauth : true, 
        cookie: true,
        channelURL : 'https://www.mydomain.com/channel.html'   
        });

      FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
      FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0); 
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>

Test
</body>
</html>
```

`

It is most definitely the calls to FB.Canvas that are generating the error. If I comment both out, no error. If I uncomment one or the other or both - Error.

The code was working fine until a few days ago. Targeting the top of the page and scaling the iframe properly. I believe this is a FB JS error.

Answer (score 14):

It seems like a bug of FireBug :)

steps of reproducing: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4991

reported: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701029

discussed: http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/2517d5f867b9f526/90f066856b45786f

so take it easy :)

Comment: updated firebug to 1.92b. Still does it, in fact, it's throwing even more errors than before.
IE8.0.6 is throwing Permission Denied errors in CANVAS_PROXY.PHP (Line 89, col 3) served from https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/canvas_proxy.php?version=3

Comment: This is not a FireBug issue. And it hasn't been solved yet, check https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701029

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the ff or the fb plugin is the firebug. I checked A page with ff 8.0 and firebug 1.84 and got the error. Then I checked ff 8.0 with firebug 1.8.3.

This is the compatibility table:
    Firefox 3.6 with Firebug 1.7.3

```
Firefox 4.0 with Firebug 1.7.3

Firefox 5.0 with Firebug 1.8.2 (and also Firebug 1.7.3)

Firefox 6.0 with Firebug 1.8.2 (and also Firebug 1.9 alpha)

Firefox 7.0 with Firebug 1.8.2 (and also Firebug 1.9 alpha)

Firefox 8.0 with Firebug 1.8.3 (and also Firebug 1.9 alpha)

Firefox 9.0 with Firebug 1.8.4 (and also Firebug 1.9 alpha)

Firefox 10.0 with Firebug 1.9 alpha
```

So... don't worry be happy. Is not a real error... I think. :P

Comment: This is fixed in Firebug 1.9. I just installed 1.9 beta 4 and it is fixed.

Comment: That's a good thing to hear... when I was testing it beta wasn't released yet. I'll test it tomorrow. Ty.

Comment: I have Firefox 8.0. Both Firebug 1.8.3 and 1.8.4 caused this problem for me. But with 1.9 beta5 the problem is gone.