# Permission denied for to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger

Tags: exception, permissions, permission-denied

the index page throws the exception
"Permission denied for to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger"
I think its a glitch due to the application setting in facebook. How to resolve it.Please help me 
Got this error on this link http://digitalblog.weebly.com/index.html

Answer (score 4):

See [Uncaught Exception: Permission denied to Proxy.InstallTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251540/uncaught-exception-permission-denied-to-proxy-installtrigger) for some more answers about this. It's *not* a bug in Firebug

Comment: The most voted answer there also suggests that it's bug in Firebug.

Comment: It "suggests" that, but the second comment states that it is not. Just have a look at the bug report at Bugzilla, where people mention the exception been thrown without having Firebug installed!

Answer (score 1):

If your seeing this in Firebug it's a bug in Firebug itself.

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4991